# How can one compute the multiplicity of a root?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, derivatives

Suppose there is a differentiable polynomial $p(x)$ of degree $n$ with a known root $x_r$. What is the multiplicity $m$ of the root $x_r$ in terms of the polynomial, its derivative(s), and/or the factor $(x-x_r)$?

Comment: Hint: use [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule) to find the multiplicity of $x_r$ as a root of derivatives of $p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The multiplicity is $m=\max\{m':\exists a\,(x-x_r)^{m'}\sum_{k=1}^{n-m'}a_kx^k=p(x)\}$. You can determine $m$ using [polynomial division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division), that is, you iteratively divide $p(x)$ by $x-x_r$ and stop when the remainder does not vanish anymore.
The benefit of this approach is that you get the decomposition.
This is equivalent to saying that $m=\max\{m':\exists g\in C(\mathbb R)\,\forall x\neq x_r\,g(x)=p(x)/(x-x_r)^{m'}\}$ is the maximal exponent $m'$ such that $p(x)/(x-x_r)^{m'}$ has a removable discontinuity at $x_r$.
Alternatively, you can view $m=\max\{m':\forall a\exists C\forall x\in[-a,a]\setminus\{x_r\}\,|p(x)/(x-x_r)^{m'}|<C\}$ as the maximal exponent $m'$ such that $p(x)/(x-x_r)^{m'}$ is locally bounded.
Alternatively, you can compute the derivatives $p^{(k)}(x)$ of $p(x)$ and check if $x_r$ is a root of $p^{(k)}(x)$. That is, you can use $m=\max\{k+1:p^{(k)}(x_r)=0\}$. Here, we recall that all polynomials are infinitely many times differentiable/smooth/analytic.
Since there are hundreds of characterizations, providing an exhaustive list is not feasible.

Comment: Many thanks! This works for me.